# Ruby: How to add 10 years to DateTime.now

Tags: ruby

In ruby I am using `DateTime.now.next_year.to_time` to get the time and date of a day one year from now.  This now needs to be changed to 10 years.  How can I do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
 DateTime.now.next_year(10).to_time
 #=> 2027-04-14 20:40:38 +0000
```

Accepts negative numbers too and does what you'd expect.

Comment: Sometimes it's worth asking yourself "How would I implement such a feature?" and then take a punt:).

Answer (score 6):

The [Date#next_year](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_year) method takes an argument on how many years to advance

```
DateTime.now.next_year(10).to_time
#=> 2027-04-14 16:41:09 -0400
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using [ActiveSupport](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport), you can require Time from active support like so:

```
require "active_support/time"
```

then you could just do this to get a `DateTime` object back:

```
DateTime.now + 10.years
=> Thu, 15 Apr 2027 13:02:15 +0000
```

or if you want a `Time` object instead:

```
DateTime.now.to_time + 10.years
=> 2027-04-15 13:02:15 +0000
```

Comment: `10.years` or specifically `years` is a method added by Rails and not found in plain Ruby.

Comment: Yes you're right, I'll change my answer to mention that this can be done only if you're using ActiveSupport.